# NHibernate inteceptor not called for changes in many-to-many set/list

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many, interceptor, iinterceptor

I have an application that uses NHibrenate and I'm using an interceptor based solution for logging/auditing.

Basically I have a class inheriting from EmptyInterceptor and overriding OnFlushDirty, OnSave and OnDelete.

Everything works perfectly - except - when I add or remove from a set or list that is mapped using many-to-many without changing any other properties none of the interceptor methods are called.

How can I hook into NHibrenate and detect those changes?

The class looks like:

```
public class SomeClass
{
  ... properties ..
  private Iesi.Collections.ISet _setOfOthers = new Iesi.Collections.HashedSet();
  public virtual Iesi.Collections.ISet SetOfOthers
  {
    get { return _setOfOthers; }
    set { _setOfOthers = value; }       
  }
  ... some more properties ...
```

}

With this hbm mapping:

```
<class name="MyAssembly.SomeClass, MyAssembly" table="[SomeClass]">
   ... properties ..
   <set name="SetOfOthers" table="SomeClass_SetOfOthers" cascade="none">
      <key column="Owner" />
      <many-to-many column="Item" class="MyAssembly.OtherClass, MyAssembly" />
   </set>
   .. some more properties ...
</class>
```

I'm using NHibrenate 2.0.1 (if that makes any difference), this is not a good time in the project life cycle to upgrade NHibrenate - but I will upgrade if I absolutely have to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should override [onCollectionUpdate](http://www.vifir.com/projectdoc/hibernate32/org/hibernate/EmptyInterceptor.html#onCollectionUpdate%28java.lang.Object,%20java.io.Serializable%29) of the Interceptor.

Than use collection as [IPersistentCollection](http://elliottjorgensen.com/nhibernate-api-ref/NHibernate.Collection/IPersistentCollection.html) to access its CollectionSnapshot and Owner.

And Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

How is your configuration and session setup implemented?

Do you associated the Interceptor with the configuration like this?

```
config.SetInterceptor(new YouInterceptor());
```

And then open the session passing it as a parameter like this?

```
if (config.Interceptor != null)
{
    session = factory.OpenSession(config.Interceptor);
}
else
{
    session = factory.OpenSession();
}
```

Comment: Hi, you misunderstood my question (my fault, I wasn't specific enough) I've set the interceptor and the interceptor methods are called for everything except when I add or remove from a set or list that is mapped using many-to-many without changing any other properties.